# Print all subexpressions of a logical expression by omitting one condition each time

Tags: arrays, perl, join

Using perl, i would like to print all subexpressions that I can get by omitting exactly one of the conditions in the main expression.

So if this is the input: **C1 and C2 and C3 and C4**
This should be the output (the order also matters, i want to omit the first element, then the second etc.):

C2 and C3 and C4 (first element missing)
C1 and C3 and C4 (second element missing)
C1 and C2 and C4 (third element missing)
C1 and C2 and C3 (fourth element missing)

Note that my expressions only use AND as conjunctions. I know how to split the original expression into conditions:

`my @CONDITIONS = split( / and /, $line );`

I also know I could do what I want using two nested loops and some if/else to properly handle the conjunction placements, BUT i'm quite sure a more elegant perl solution is out there. But for the life of me i cannot figure it out on my own. Basicaly what i'm asking is if there is a way how to `join` an array without the i-th element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i like your Problem. Based on your expected output comes my solution:

```
my $string = "C1 and C2 and C3 and C4";
my @split = split / and /, $string;

for my $counter (0..$#split) {
  print join ' and ', grep { $_ !~ /$split[$counter]/ } @split;
  print "\n";
}
```

Explain:

The magic here is the `grep` which only `greps` the entries of `@split` which does not contain the part which is at the current index of the loop. For example we start at index `0`:

```
# $counter == 0
# $split[$counter] contains C1
# grep goes through @split and only takes the parts of @split 
# which does not contain C1, because its inside $split[$counter]
# 
# the next loop set $counter to 1 
# $split[$counter] contains C2 now and the 
# grep just grep again only the stuff of @split which does not contain C2
# that way, we just take the parts of @split which are not at the current loop
# position inside @split :)
```

EDIT:

note that my stuff does not work with Strings with duplicate entries:

```
my $string = "C1 and C2 and C3 and C4 and C4";
```

Output:

```
C2 and C3 and C4 and C4
C1 and C3 and C4 and C4
C1 and C2 and C4 and C4
C1 and C2 and C3
C1 and C2 and C3
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed works. Can you please explain how the line where `grep` is used works?